# Conditional Probability of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Given that  $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$ with  $X$~ $N_3(\mu, \Sigma)$ for some known $\mu, \Sigma$

How do I compute $P(X_1 | \bar{X} = 6)$ ?

If I use conditional probability formula : $P(X_1 | \bar{X}) = \frac{P(X_1, \bar{X})}{P(\bar{X})}$, how do I find the Joint probability of $X_1$ and $\bar{X}$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $E(X_1|\overline X)$?

Comment: Do you mean joint probability **density**?

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, the joint density $P(X_1 | \bar{X})$ , is there another you can find of the probability of $P(X_1 | \bar{X} = 6) $ ?

Comment: Your notation $P(X_1 | \bar{X})$ does not make sense for a conditional density. This is not a probability.